# executing a .sh and ending in a different directory

Tags: command-line, directory

I know there is a simple command for this, but I'm trying to run a file.sh, which contains lines like:

```
mkdir $filename
cd $filename
```

the file executes, but ends in the file i began in. I know there is a simple keyword to put in front to make the execution leave me in the directory $filename, but i cant find it on the internet. I found it once before, but cant seem to do it again.

Answer (score 4):

According to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

you can run your script using

`. ./scriptname`

and it will run the shell script with your shell, not invoking a subshell like what usually happens.

Comment: take care of replacing any "exit ..." by "return ..." otherwise it will exit the invoking shell, ie the one you typed the `. ./scriptname` in, closing it.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a shell script, it is equivalent of running it in an different shell. Doing `./script.sh` is equal to `sh script.sh`, which may open the problem better for you.

To run the script in current shell context, you need to use `source` or its alias `.`, ie `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`.

Easiest solution for simple operation like this would be to create an alias instead of a script, ie. `alias mkcd='mkdir dir; cd dir'` or if you need to run arbitrary directories, you can do `mkcd() { mkdir $1; cd $1 }` function. You can put either of these into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.